# Any way to get my ethernet to work without installing a non-free driver?

Tags: debian, firmware, realtek, free-software

I'm trying to purge myself of all non-free software (using debian jessie) and the last thing remaining is firmware-realtek. Because you know, I want my ethernet to work. Is there any way I can get some functionality out of it with free software? It doesn't need to work well, it just needs to work. I've found some non-free software has partial free substitutes, like GNU Gnash with flash player. It's not totally reverse engineered but it's better than nothing.
Relevant hardware:

```
01:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.        
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
Subsystem: COMPAL Electronics Inc Device 0075
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- 
Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- 
<MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 60
Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Region 2: Memory at b0610000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Region 4: Memory at b0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA 
PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Address: 00000000fee0f00c  Data: 41c1
Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 01
DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s 
unlimited, L1 <64us
ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- 
ABWMgmt-
DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not 
Supported
DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF 
Disabled
LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, 
EqualizationPhase1-
EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
Vector table: BAR=4 offset=00000000
PBA: BAR=4 offset=00000800
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
Unknown small resource type 00, will not decode more.
Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- 
ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- 
ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ 
ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
CESta:  RxErr+ BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Which hardware are you using exactly? Try posting "lspci -vv" output here.

Comment: thanks a lot i've never used double verbose with lscpi, super convenient